# How to change field value before display?

Tags: 7, entities

I have defined custom Integer field in commerce product entity. I would like to achieve, that if field should be displayed on the website (i.e. in some view) and if field `value == -1`, then text string `t('Unlimited')` should be displayed instead of field value.

Is it possible to change field value before display? I would like to change only output of the field value, not value in database.

I have created field using UI, not programatically, so I think I cannot use many of hooks concerning fields like `hook_field_prepare_view`.

I don't want to use preprocess function in my theme, because I would prefer solution that will work independent on current theme.

Comment: do you use fields display in views OR teasers?

Comment: Preprocess functions work equally well in modules as they do in themes; so there's no need to put the logic in a theme